# How to find the end of a binary file?

Tags: c, file, fopen

I have opened a binary file as below

```
FILE *p;
p=fopen("filename.format","rb");
```

How can I find the end of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fread function `fread` returns the number of bytes actually read. So if the number of bytes read is lower that the number of bytes to be read, you are likely at the end of file.

Furthermore the `feof` function will also tell you if you are at the end of the file.

To find out the size of the file without actually reading it:

```
  long Size;
  FILE *p;
  p = fopen("filename.format","rb");
  fseek (p, 0 , SEEK_END);
  Size = ftell (p) ;
  rewind (p);
```

Comment: great answer sir..genius

Comment: According to the standard "A binary stream need not
meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END." so does this actually work in the general case?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ I usually jump to the end of the file using `ifstream::seekg` and giving it the `ios::end` argument for position. The ANSI-C equivalent of `seekg` is

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

Where `origin` can be `SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END`.
Trying this would jump to the end of the file:

```
fseek(p, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Then, once at the end of the file, just use

```
long int ftell ( FILE * stream );
```

to tell your program where the file ends.
For an example, the following code would set the `size` variable to the physical size - in bytes - of the file, and then jump back to the beginning of the file:

```
FILE *p = fopen("filename.format", "rb"); // open binary file

fseek(p, 0, SEEK_END); // jump to end of file

long int size = ftell(p); // get size of file

fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET); // jump back to beginning of file
```

Comment: According to the standard "A binary stream need not
meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END." so does this actually work in the general case?

Comment: Yes, if you're working with a stream (e.g., a linux 'file' device or 'stdin'), there's no definite way of telling the length of it, as it can technically indefinitely provide data as long as it's being asked for more. As the question pertains specifically to files, this solution (along with Michael's) will work.